# How to get the value of an option in javascript parsing

Tags: javascript, html

Good day 
am having an HTML code in which i intend to get the innerText of a selected option

```
<div class="bag-option">
<div class="bag-option-label">colour:</div>
<div class="bag-option-control">
    <select name='select-colour-0' id='select-colour-0' onchange="onColourSelected(this, '0', '1', 'style-img-thb-', '_WLG.jpg', '_WXL.jpg', '_SKC.jpg');displayUpdateMsg();return false;">
        <option value="0" selected>orchid pink</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: the aim is to get "orchid pink"

Answer (score 0):

You can get using:

```
document.getElementById("select-colour-0").getElementsByTagName("option")[document.getElementById("select-colour-0").selectedIndex].innerHTML
```

What exactly the code does is:

1. Select the `<select>` tag.
2. Get find all the `<option>` tags.
3. Get the `selectedIndex` of the `<select>`.
4. Get the particular `<option>` tag with the `selectedIndex`.
5. Get the `innerHTML` of the `<option>` which is always a text.

A working demo of the code is below...

**Snippet**

```html
<select name='select-colour-0' id='select-colour-0' onchange="onColourSelected(this, '0', '1', 'style-img-thb-', '_WLG.jpg', '_WXL.jpg', '_SKC.jpg');displayUpdateMsg();return false;">
  <option value="0" selected>orchid pink</option>
</select>
<script>
  alert(document.getElementById("select-colour-0").getElementsByTagName("option")[document.getElementById("select-colour-0").selectedIndex].innerHTML);
</script>
```